# Hot Deploy Does Not Work For Java Class File Edits On Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, weblogic12c, hotdeploy

I'm using Intellij Community edition I don't have the luxurary of using the Ultimate edition; Hence, I can't install the weblogic plugin. When I make edits to any class file it will not hot deploy to the server.  Is there a way to configure weblogic so that hot deploys are picked up.

Answer (score 0):

WLS has FastSwap, which is a hot redeploy feature, although has some [limitations](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/DEPGD/deployunits.htm#DEPGD162), and probably not as good as the mentioned plug-in.

**TL;DR:**
To enable FastSwap in your application, add the following element to the `weblogic-application.xml` file.

```
 <fast-swap>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
 </fast-swap>
```

more details at:

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/DEPGD/deployunits.htm#DEPGD153

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can try the [Manik-Hotdeploy-Maven-Plugin](https://manik.imixs.org/)

Manik-Hot-Deploy is an Open Source Maven Plugin which brings hot-deploy to the development of web applications. This is independent form your IDE or Application server. You just have to configure the target folders of your server.